# PDF file attached inside app but doesn't send using android Intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I'm sending pdf file from sd card to an email address by using android intent. It shows me attached pdf file but this attached file gets disappear at reviver side. I don't know where I'm doing wrong. here is my code

```
          String[] mailto = {"me@hotmail.com"};
          Uri uri = Uri.parse(getExternalFilesDir(filepath)+"/"+filename);

          Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testing");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hoooo");
          emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for sharing pdf files via gmail.

```
 Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mSubjectEditText.getText().toString());

 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mBodyEditText.getText().toString());

 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + myFile.getAbsolutePath());

 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

 email.setType("message/rfc822");

 startActivity(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my working code for sharing pdf files via gmail.

```
    ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayList<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    uriList.add(Uri.fromFile(f));
    fileNameList.add(f.getName());

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[]{""});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC,
            new String[]{""});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Heres the PDF you wanted!");

    if (!uriList.isEmpty()) {
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
        emailIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fileNameList);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Dude, its not working :( it is giving me warning message "couldn't show attachment".

Comment: Then your pdf is probably messed up. This code is used in a production app for a multi million dollar company, and is a core feature. If it didnt work I think I would have heard so by now :P

Comment: I can promise you,  something about your `File f` is then wrong. ensure your file exists and is valid.

Comment: I've attached same file and send it by using gmail app in my device and it is working. The problem is within my app, it shows attachment but don't send.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is on Uri.

```
Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        MainActivity.this,
        "com.example.homefolder.example.provider", //(use your app signature + ".provider" )
        pdfFile);
```

No manifest

```
<application>
 ...
  <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.homefolder.example.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <!-- ressource file to create -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths">  
    </meta-data>
  </provider>
</application>
```

so

```
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```